# electrical Socket not getting power

Tags: switch, socket

I have a single pole switch that feeds power to a wall socket.

with the switch ON, and the wire that feeds the switch disconnected from the socket, the point on the switch shows 120V.
with the switch OFF and the wire that feeds the switch disconnected from the socket, the point on the switch shows 0V
So, the switch seems to be working
However with the wire that feeds to the socket connected to the switch, the voltage drops to 0V at that connection point when the switch is turned on

nothing is connected to the socket

HELP

Comment: Could be an internal switch failure that only manifests when the terminal screw is tightened? Try removing the switch and directly connecting the hot and "switched hot" (or using a jumper wire across the switch). If the receptacle functions then you have a bad switch.

Comment: I just did that (directly connecting the hot and "switched hot") and the receptacle worked. Thanks a bunch. Will replace switch.

Answer (score 1):

Could be an internal switch failure that only manifests when the terminal screw is tightened? Try removing the switch and directly connecting the hot and "switched hot" (or using a jumper wire across the switch). If the receptacle functions then you have a bad switch.